# How to view git commit history?

Tags: git, history, commit

I'm developing a Django app and I upload the new versions to Heroku simply by:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push heroku master
```

is there any way I can display these commits (either on Heroku or my local directory) so that I get a result like this:

```
date           | message
17.10.16 16:58 | "commit message 1"
18.10.16 16:58 | "commit message 2"
..etc,
```

so I can review what I have changed and when?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display commit history with full messages:

```
git log
```

For a more compact log:

```
git log --oneline
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `git log` to see the history log. Of course, you'll need to clone it from it's repo first.